# JAWS screen reader should read only error messages

Tags: testing, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

Currently, I am refreshing the page and focusing on error messages so that jaws can read it. But it is reading all the way from error messages till bottom of the page which is default behavior. Is there any way I can restrict JAWS to read only error messages and not all the text below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about accessibility, the default behavior is often the best way to do.

That being said using `role=alert` seems to be a better way to announce error messages.